# Pong in assembly waiting for input instead of moving the ball

Tags: assembly

I am writing pong in assembly x86 with TASM and I have a problem.

The program is waiting to get input from the user to move the paddle (int 16h ah=0h) and while it is waiting the ball and the other paddle doesn't move.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Most of the keyboard interrupts that return data from the keyboard buffer (that is, most of the interrupt 16h family) block if there is not actually *in* the keyboard buffer.

What you need to do instead is first check if there's anything in the keyboard buffer. If there is, you can issue `int 16h / AH = 0`. Otherwise just continue with your regular game loop.

[`int 16h / AH = 1`](http://h4xxel.org/asm/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.html#int16h_01h) can be used to check if there's anything in the buffer. It will set `ZF` to 0 if there's a key available for you to read.